# JPA Query with IN clause

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

I am using the Google App Engine and JPA. I tried to execute the following query

```
List<String> countryList = new ArrayList<String>();
countryList.add("DE");
countryList.add("EN");      

Query q = em.createQuery("select t from FOO t where t.country IN :country ");
q.setParameter("country", countryList);
```

I receive the Exception that Google App Engine Datastore does not support the IN Opperator. Does anyone know a suitable alternative?

Regards

Michael

Comment: Is that your actual query? You probably have other exceptions due to the syntax error in your query (if that's not your actual query, please edit your question and include valid testable code).

Comment: It should be something like `select t from FOO t where t.country in :country` *if* `country` is a property of `FOO`.

Comment: ok, I corrected the query in my question, there is no other syntax error in the query